# <select> no php

Tags: php

Como faço para enviar dados pelo select sem perder os anteriores no php? Toda vez que envio o mesmo é substituído =/

Segue o meu código:

Ex:

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="teste[]">
    <option>Selecionar</option>
    <option value="Teste1">TESTE 1</option>
    <option value="Teste2">TESTE 2</option>
    <option value="Teste3">TESTE 3</option>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</select>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['teste'])){

    $teste = $_POST['teste'];

    foreach($teste as $k){
        echo $k."<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Segue Código completo<form method="POST">
<select name="teste[]">
 <option>Selecionar</option>
 <option value="Teste1">TESTE 1</option>
 <option value="Teste2">TESTE 2</option>
 <option value="Teste3">TESTE 3</option>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</select>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['teste'])){

 $teste = $_POST['teste'];

 foreach($teste as $k){
  echo $k."<br>";
 }
}


?>

Comment: Você pode [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/287100/edit) sua pergunta e adicionar o código, para formatar selecione o código e aperte o atalho `CTRL+K`

Comment: Não seria o caso de utilizar o atributo `multiple`? ... `<select name="teste[]" multiple="multiple">`

Comment: Até seria, porém o cliente teria que segurar o Ctrl p/ selecionar mais de 1 - vê se vc poderia me sugerir algo melhor amigo. A minha ideia seria :
 - Cliente selecionar o item que deseja e por a quantidade. Até agora não encontrei uma melhor solução =/

Comment: Outra opção seria utilizar `checkbox` .... `<input type="checkbox" name="teste[]" value="Teste1"> Teste 1`

Comment: Você pode usar jquery para ao clicar no campo, ele insere em um form um item de lista já com o nome que você clicou e na frente um campo para colocar a quantidade, assim a cada clique ele cria uma novo item, no final dessa  form você deixa o botão de enviar

Comment: Vou fazer um exemplo aqui, só um momento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá uma olhada, utilizei bootstrap e jquery:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Twitter clone</title>

        <!-- jquery - link cdn -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="icon" href="imagens/icone.png">

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function(){

                $("#add").click(function() {
                    var v = '<a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>' + $("#v1 option:selected").val() + '</strong>  -  <input type="text" name="valor" placeholder"Digite o valor"></a>';
                    $('#form_pro').append(v);

                }); 
            });

            //Apos adicionar tudo que você quis, vc faz a requisição ajax para seu arquivo php

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select name="teste" id="v1" class="form-control">
                    <option>Selecionar</option>
                    <option value="Teste1">TESTE 1</option>
                    <option value="Teste2">TESTE 2</option>
                    <option value="Teste3">TESTE 3</option>

                </select>

                <button id='add'>Adicionar</button>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form id="form_pro" class="list-group">
                            <!--Dados são inseridos aqui-->

                        </form>
                        <button>Requisitar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        </div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Para fazer a requisição para o arquivo php eu recomendo que use ajax, é bem fácil, só dar uma olhada em exemplos de jquery. Mas no mais é isso, agora só recuperar os valores e fazer a requisição com ajax que fica tudo tranquilo, espero ter ajudado

Comment: Amigo não sabia que o Ajax é tão poderoso p/ esse tipo operação (confesso e meu conhecimento em Ajax e Jquery é quase 0). Desde de já mais que agradecido irmão. Irei me aprofundar neles. Brigadão!!!

Comment: @MaxwellGomes e se eu te falar que comecei aprender ajax ontem kkkkkkkkk, meu conhecimento era totalmente 0 também, mas vi que é bem fácil até, fico feliz que resolveu seu problema aí

Comment: Nossa cara! Então parabéns ae rsrs... Vou começar hoje, comprei um curso EAD, vou começar hoje. Alguma sugestão de cursos?

Comment: @MaxwellGomes Estou fazendo esse: https://www.udemy.com/curso-completo-do-desenvolvedor-web/learn/v4/ achei ele muito bom

Comment: Obrigado irmão !